# How to set the anchor tag color while keeping the cursor above on it

Tags: css

I am new CSS .
I have done some coding

```
 #IconHover:hover {
    background-color: #F18B13;
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    width: 180px;
}
a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```
<table id="IconHover">
  <tr>
   <td><img src="~/content/iconmaster/user_info.png" width="50" height="50" /></td>
       <td style="padding:10px;"                                                          
         @Html.ActionLink("Personal Identity", "PersonalIdentity", "PersonalData")</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

This code is running fine.
  When i am keeping the cursor the background color is changing but the text color is not changing ,
 when i am keeping the cursor above on the text then only the color is changing ,but i want to do when i will keep the cursor on the image the text color should become white ?

Can anyone help me out to solve this problem ?

Comment: I suggest creating a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the basic HTML/CSS needed to reproduce the issue. It'll be easier for people to help you if they don't need to figure out the .NET code you're using.

Comment: You can't. Image and link have different parents. You must change the markup.

Comment: You didn't close the opening <td> before @Html.ActionLink

Comment: thanks @StevenRichards next time onwards i will do ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a class for `#IconHover:hover a` also:

```
#IconHover:hover a
{
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Check the JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/29cquvsf/.